# How to allow rectangeSelector to select edge of plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt

I have a pyQt interface where the user can select a region of a matplotlib plot using `rectangleSelector`.  My issue is the if the user wants to select a region including the edge of the visible region of the plot, it always stops short.  Depending how fast the mouse is moved, it may fall far short.  It appears that the box stops updating once the mouse exists the plot axes. This is in contrast to, for example, the built-in magnifying glass selector, which allows the user to drag a box far outside the plot region.  Is there a way to force `rectangleSelector` to select beyond, or at least right up to, the visible plotted areas?

Comment: please provide a [mre]